# Index on SUM function in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query in MYSQL like this (simplified) :

```
SELECT col1, SUM(DISTINCT col2) AS S
FROM tbl1
WHERE col1='abbc'
GROUP BY col1
ORDER BY S ASC
```

I know that an index on col1 would be useful for that kind of query. I would like to know if a covering index on (col1, col2) would be more usefull or if it doesnt make any difference.

Comment: The question is not clear. Always prefer to ask in the understanding context.

Comment: I have never used `SUM(DISTINCT)`.  I cannot think of a valid situation.

Comment: Quite tricky question. I suppose that "in theory" covering index must be useful even without `DISTINCT col2`. In practice - it needs experiments.

Comment: @gordonlinoff Bill is busy Monday (1), Tuesday (2), Wednesday (4), and Thursday (8). Ben is busy Thursday, Friday (16), and Saturday (32). Subtract the sum of the distinct values from 127 and you get 64 (Sunday)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i try it , it seems different and more usefull

---

### Index Version Execution Plan :

without distinct

```
SELECT col1, SUM(col2) AS S
FROM tbl1
WHERE col1='abbc'
GROUP BY col1
ORDER BY S ASC;
```

[image]

distinct

```
SELECT col1, SUM(distinct col2) AS S
FROM tbl1
WHERE col1='abbc'
GROUP BY col1
ORDER BY S ASC;
```

[image]

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f42dc0/1/0)

---

### without Index Version Execution Plan :

it's no different
[image]

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5e695/1/0)